# How to provide CSS rules based on viewport height of different devices

Tags: css, angular, sass, responsive-design, compass-sass

How can I provide in an Angular or any other application CSS/SCSS rules that respond to the viewport height of different devices?

The viewport width is not a problem with `@media (max-width: ...) {}`, but how can I react to the height here?

For example, a 13-inch Macbook, 15-inch Macbook, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple just like `max-width` eg:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 995px) , screen and (max-height: 700px) {
  ...
}
```

For further help
[Read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: Cool :) ! same here i didn't use that either till now but i had read that as i start working on media quires:_) Cheers!